# Finding a single user record in some incomplete data?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I am in the process of building a system in which users must sign up.  These users are likely to also be part of a larger customer database and I'd like to tie the sign up with the user ID in the larger customer database.

The customer database is somewhat incomplete.  Some customers just have a telephone number, and it may have spaces in various places depending on who/what entered it.  Other customers have just an email address, and it may well have typos in due to it being hand-written and then processed at a later date by somebody else.  Quite the nightmare really.

I would like to find the closest record to what the user has inputted on the system I am building.  That data is pretty straight forward, and will be validated.  That data:

- First name
- Last name
- DOB (YYYY-MM-DD)
- Email address
- Telephone number

My initial thought is to use a Levenshtein distance algorithm to calculate the 'string distance' for each of the fields, unless they're empty, and then order by an overall score.  Not shown in the below code to keep things nice and readable, but I'll obviously trim (possibly even just remove) all whitespace too.

As pseudo code:

```
SELECT c.customerID
FROM   customers c
WHERE  ( c.first_name IS NULL OR ( Levenshtein(c.first_name, $first_name) < 3 ) )
AND    ( c.last_name IS NULL OR ( Levenshtein(c.last_name, $last_name) < 3 ) )
AND    ( c.email IS NULL OR ( Levenshtein(c.email, $email) < 3 ) )
AND    ( c.telephone IS NULL OR ( Levenshtein(c.telephone, $telephone) < 3 ) )
```

Just FYI I'm using PHP (Laravel) and MySQL for both databases.

Am I on the right track here or should I use something other than Levenshtein?  Should I compare some sort of combination of all fields scores?

Answer (score 0):

The track is definitely right, but I'd add a few notes.

**Preparing the data**

First of all, for the sake of matching I recommend transforming the data to eliminate possibly all the noise, f.i. convert strings to uppercase, remove whitespace, remove all non-digits from phone numbers, etc.

**Finding a closest match in incomplete data**

Secondly, setting arbitrary thresholds ( like "less than 3" above ) makes it a bit stiff. Although more CPU-demanding, you may be better off sorting the results by the "difference factor":

```
SELECT c.customerID
FROM   customers c
ORDER BY
Levenshtein(c.first_name, $first_name)) +
Levenshtein(c.last_name, $last_name) +
Levenshtein(c.email, $email) +
Levenshtein(c.telephone, $telephone) asc
LIMIT 0,1;
```

Obviously, you can add some safety not to match when the differences are ridiculously high, but you get the idea. In cases where both objects lack data in the same field (eg. both are missing email), the approach is still OK. Problems arise when just one side is missing - then we get a big kick for the difference. We might complicate the query a bit further to avoid it:

```
ORDER BY
(if(c.first_name is null OR c.first_name = '' OR $first_name = '', 0, Levenshtein(c.first_name, $first_name))) +
...
```

Shortened to one line for brevity - we calculate the Lev dist only if there's data to compare.

**Shortcomings**

For all the records matched with a diff factor greater than X you might think of some kind of flag to let humans decide. After some time spent reviewing I'm sure you'd come up with more rules to automate it.

Comment: Cool.  That makes sense.  I'd be preparing the data as best as possible like you mentioned.  My worry with the above is that there may not be an existing customer in the database at all.  There might even be rows without this data (we might just have an address, for example, which I don't collect), so comparing NULL and NULL would result in a perfect match.

Comment: Right, but I think it makes sense - if there's no data in a specific property on both sides, it just does not affect the factor. No data at all (in any field) would be a problem - but that's validation. Let me update the anwer a bit.